# Allow <a> tags in a mdl-layout__tab-bar to function as actual <a> tags

Tags: material-design-lite

Is there any way to disable the MDL javascript that prevents any `<a>` tags within a `mdl-layout__tab-bar` from changing the URL? By default they only change the `mdl-layout__content` and leave the URL-state but that won't work for this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem. My solution was to by-pass via a new css tag. I simply copied the default css.

If someone else needs it... this is the css styling for the tag:

```
.foo {
      height: 48px;
      line-height: 48px;
      float:none;
      -webkit-box-flex:1;
      -webkit-flex-grow:1;
      -ms-flex-positive:1;
      flex-grow:1;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      border:none;
      padding:0 24px;
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      -webkit-box-flex:0;
      -webkit-flex-grow:0;
      -ms-flex-positive:0;
      flex-grow:0;
      -webkit-flex-shrink:0;
      -ms-flex-negative:0;
      flex-shrink:0;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-align:center;
      font-weight:500;
      font-size:14px;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      color:rgba(255,255,255,.6);
      overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: So did you give the 'foo' class to the link instead of `mdl-layout__tab`?

Comment: This worked for me! With the MDL template I was using, though, it set the line height to 64 and not 48. So all I had to do was change that. Just commenting so future readers will know. :)